# Creating simple frames

Tags: framed

I want some of my text to be "framed".  So far, I have horizontal lines generated by the `\separate` command in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\separate{\medskip\hrule\medskip} % nice page-long underscores
\begin{document}
Here is introductory text.
\separate
Here is text in the frame.
\separate
Here is concluding text.
\end{document}
```

Two questions:

1) How do I make the horizontal line extend just a tiny bit longer into the outer margin?  (So that it runs just .2 inches or so beyond the text its framing...)

2) How do I add code generate little vertical lines to the horizontal ones?  I want the "frame" to end up looking something like the following:

```
 ----------------------------
|

                            |
----------------------------
```

EDIT:

To be more specific, I want this to work with the `fullwidth` environment, as in the following (updated) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullwidth}
\newcommand\separate{\medskip\hrule\medskip} % nice page-long underscores
\begin{document}

Here is introductory text.

\begin{fullwidth}[outermargin = -4cm, width = \linewidth + 4cm]
\separate
Here is text in the frame
\separate
\end{fullwidth}

Here is concluding text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case you should work with mdframed. A similar example is given in the documentation. Please have a look at example 7 in the file [`mdframed-example-default.pdf`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Non-TikZ solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,lipsum}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\def\boxit #1{%
    \parindent0pt
    \leavevmode
    \hbox{\vbox{%
     \hrule
      %
        \vbox to 0pt{\vrule height50pt width1pt}
            \leftskip10pt\rightskip10pt
            \vskip10pt%  
            #1%
   \vskip-50pt\vbox to 0pt{\hskip\dimexpr\hsize-10pt\relax\vrule height50pt width1pt}
    \vskip50pt
    \hrule
   }%
}}
\boxit{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

To work with fullwidth package minor adjustments were necessary; the full code with a key-value interface is a bit long so I pasted it at https://gist.github.com/1971055.

Comment: When I try to use this in the `fullwidth` environment, the bottom-right vertical line gets pushed away, and I also get an `overfull hbox` warning.  Please see the `EDIT` to my question.  Also, is there any way to make this vertical lines shorter?  Also also, would it be possible to define `boxit` as an environment, that can be begun and ended?

Comment: @jamaicanworm Please see edit. It works with `fullwidth` and vertical lines shortened. Please post a comment if this is ok, I will polish the code a bit and make it more user friendly.

Comment: It looks better, but it still gives an `overfull hbox` warning.  Also, now the vertical line looks to thick, and looks slightly detached from the horizontal lines...

Comment: @jamaicanworm It actually looks awful with the parameters you specified for fullwidth:), that is also why we get the overful box. Line thickness etc... is easy to get. Do you have a scan of a sample of what you want perhaps from a book? The thickness of the lines is given by width is the same as before!

Comment: Ideally it would look exactly like the first picture you provided (albeit with slightly shorter vertical lines), but in the `fullwidth` environment.

Comment: @jamaicanworm Made the vrules shorter and thinner. If you want to change, try changing all the 20pt to something else.

Comment: Now it looks great!  Is there any way to get rid of that pesky `overfull hbox` warning, or should I just learn to live with it?  Also, might it please be possible to define `boxit` as an environment with `\begin{boxit}` and `\end{boxit}` commands?  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @jamaicanworm Thanks, will have a good look tomorrow for the overfull and the enviro.

Comment: @jamaicanworm Please see link.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure TikZ will make an entry here, since it is much more proficient and decorative with these things. However, it is possible using a combination of rules to obtain this layout. I decided to use an environment rather than two separate macros, since it seemed to be more fitting - an environment allows for a start and end declaration.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\newenvironment{separateA}
  {\par\nobreak%
   \noindent\smash{\makebox[\textwidth]{%
     \rule[-.25\baselineskip]{.4pt}{\dimexpr.25\baselineskip+.4pt}% left hang
     \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+.4in-.8pt}{.4pt}% horizontal rule
     \rule[-.25\baselineskip]{.4pt}{\dimexpr.25\baselineskip+.4pt}% right hang
   }}}
  {\par\nobreak%
   \noindent\smash{\makebox[\textwidth]{%
     \rule[.5\baselineskip]{.4pt}{.25\baselineskip}% left hung
     \rule[.5\baselineskip]{\dimexpr\textwidth+.4in-.8pt}{.4pt}% horizontal rule
     \rule[.5\baselineskip]{.4pt}{.25\baselineskip}% right hung
   }}}
\newenvironment{separateB}
  {\par\nobreak%
   \noindent\smash{\makebox[\textwidth]{%
     \rule[-.25\baselineskip]{.4pt}{\dimexpr.25\baselineskip+.4pt}% left hang
     \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+.4in-.4pt}{.4pt}% horizontal rule
     %\rule[-.25\baselineskip]{.4pt}{\dimexpr.25\baselineskip+.4pt}% right hang
   }}}
  {\par\nobreak%
   \noindent\smash{\makebox[\textwidth]{%
     %\rule[.5\baselineskip]{.4pt}{.25\baselineskip}% left hung
     \rule[.5\baselineskip]{\dimexpr\textwidth+.4in-.4pt}{.4pt}% horizontal rule
     \rule[.5\baselineskip]{.4pt}{.25\baselineskip}% right hung
   }}}
\newenvironment{separateC}
  {\par\nobreak%
   \noindent\smash{\makebox[\textwidth]{%
     %\rule[-.25\baselineskip]{.4pt}{\dimexpr.25\baselineskip+.4pt}% left hang
     \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+.4in-.4pt}{.4pt}% horizontal rule
     \rule[-.25\baselineskip]{.4pt}{\dimexpr.25\baselineskip+.4pt}% right hang
   }}}
  {\par\nobreak%
   \noindent\smash{\makebox[\textwidth]{%
     \rule[.5\baselineskip]{.4pt}{.25\baselineskip}% left hung
     \rule[.5\baselineskip]{\dimexpr\textwidth+.4in-.4pt}{.4pt}% horizontal rule
     %\rule[.5\baselineskip]{.4pt}{.25\baselineskip}% right hung
   }}}
\begin{document}
Some fully boxed text, using \verb|separateA|:

\begin{separateA}
Here is text in the frame.
\end{separateA}

Some partially boxed text (left and right), using \verb|separateB|:

\begin{separateB}
Here is text in the frame.
\end{separateB}

Some partially boxed text (right and left), using \verb|separateC|:

\begin{separateC}
Here is text in the frame.
\end{separateC}

Here is concluding text.
\end{document}
```

The above MWE provides three environments, for the sake of difference (although they're virtually identical): `separateA` prints a "fully boxed" block, while `separateB` prints a "partially boxed" block (left and right) and `separateC` also a "partially boxed" block (right to left). Care is taken to make the horizontal separation be exactly `\textblock+.4in` wide, hanging over the edge by exactly `.2in` on either side.

It would be easy to construct a single environment (say) `separate` to do this, with optional arguments for control over the placements of the hangs/hungs.

[`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was used to highlight the text block boundary, and indicate and accentuate the overhang outside the text margin.

Comment: In the `fullwidth` environment, these vertical lines run off the page.  Please see the `EDIT` to my question.  I want the look of `separateB`, but is there a way to make the vertical lines taller?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\separate[1][]{%
  \par\noindent
  \ifx\relax#1\relax
    \makebox(0,0){\rule[-2\normalbaselineskip]{\fboxrule}{\normalbaselineskip}}%
    \kern-0.5\fboxrule\rule{1.1\textwidth}{\fboxrule}%
  \else  
    \rule{1.1\textwidth}{\fboxrule}%
    \makebox(0,0){\rule[\normalbaselineskip]{\fboxrule}{\normalbaselineskip}}%
  \fi\par}
\begin{document}
Here is introductory text.
\separate
Here is text in the frame.
\separate[up]
Here is concluding text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does `\separate[up-and-down]` also work? ;)

Comment: In the fullwidth environment, these vertical lines run off the page. Please see the EDIT to my question.  Also, when you zoom in, the vertical line looks slightly detached from the horizontal lines.  Also also, might there be a way to make these lines thinner?

Comment: See edited example, it now uses `\fboxrule`. Change the value of `1.1\textwidth` to your needs for the rule length.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Metapost solution (in ConTeXt). I define a *MPbackground* in metapost, that can then be plugged into any ConTeXt object that accepts a `background` parameter.

```
\startuniqueMPgraphic {splitframe}
  newpath topborder, bottomborder;
  newpath BackgroundBox;
  BackgroundBox := OverlayBox enlarged (0.2cm);

  bottomborder = point 0 of BackgroundBox -- point 1 of BackgroundBox 
              -- point 1.2 of BackgroundBox ;

  topborder    = point 2 of BackgroundBox -- point 3 of BackgroundBox 
              -- point 3.2 of BackgroundBox ;

  draw bottomborder withpen pencircle scaled OverlayLineWidth
       withcolor OverlayLineColor ;

  draw topborder withpen pencircle scaled OverlayLineWidth
       withcolor OverlayLineColor ;

  setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;

\stopuniqueMPgraphic

\defineoverlay [splitframe] [\uniqueMPgraphic{splitframe}]
```

As an example, consider adding a frame to a side float and a text background.

```
\definebackground
  [splitframe]
  [background=splitframe,
   rulethickness=1.5pt,
   framecolor=blue,
   width=broad,
   frame=off]

\starttext
\placefigure[right,none]{}
  {\externalfigure[cow][background=splitframe,width=0.3\textwidth,framecolor=red]}
\startsplitframe
  \input tufte
\stopsplitframe
\stoptext
```

[image]