# Create a name box on an exam

Tags: formatting, exam

Is there an easy way to put a box in the upper right corner asking for student name/number on the first page? Is there something analogous to defining the location of something on a web-page in terms of absolute positions?

I need the following criteria to be met:

- Does not use the exam class
- Puts the box inside of the margin (i.e. Does not move the title down/get in the way)

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49822/controlling-the-exact-position-of-objects-on-a-page/49823#49823

Comment: an example here http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/exam-sheet/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidCarlisle for the link in the original comments which led me to his answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47497/implementing-line-based-corporate-design-in-latex), where I found the following trick:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}

\title{Quiz Two}
\author{Batman}
\date{}
\maketitle

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(200,200){
\begin{tabular}{|r|c|}
\hline
Name: & \hspace{5cm} \\
\hline
Student Number: & ~ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{picture}


\end{document}
```

The position of the box is controlled by changing the numbers in the `\put` command.

Answer (score 3):

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[below left] (coin)  at (current page.north east)
        {\begin{tabular}{l p{3cm}}
 Last Name: & \hrule \\ 
 First Name: &\hrule  \\
 Date:& \hrule \\
\end{tabular}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]