# Forcing arbitrary figure location

Tags: floats, environments

Is there a nice way to arbitrarily force a figure into a location in the page, in an ad-hoc way. That is, after everything is written, just tell latex where to place it without changing any text.

I ma working with a CV template and don't want to change much, so I am looking for this way of achieving this. Any suggestions are welcome, thank you.

**Edit** I am not referring to in-text floats. Rather, I would like to "stick it on" in an arbitrary location.

Comment: Perhaps the [`flowfram` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) might help you.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: I don’t think this is an exact duplicate: here the question doesn’t seem to concern only in-text “floats” (that don’t actually float), but more generally the problem of disposing figures and tables in preassigned positions on the page.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a duplicate, the question is different

Comment: @splinter: I think you should edit your question so to make it clear that you are not speaking exclusively of in-text “floats”.

Comment: Do you want to change figure placement from, for example, bottom to top, or from "current page(top)" to "next page(top)"?

Comment: @PatrickHappel: No, I really want to have complete control of where to put the figure, without it having any effect on the rest of the document.

Comment: the `xor` package has a facility like this but it's incompatible with everything so not really ready for production use yet.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Vote retracted (but there are two more...)

Comment: @Werner: I apologize for insisting on this point, but I still think that this question is *not* a duplicate of [Force figure placement in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625/69818); indeed, both answers to that question exclusively deal with placing the float in-text, whereas the OP has made it very clear that this question is about how to control the placement of floats in *arbitrary* positions.  For example: how to force a certain float to be moved to the top of a certain physical page, and nowhere else?  That was precisely what made me think of the `flowfram` package.

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti How do you know about the flowfram package? Never heard of it before. Looks very interesting.

Comment: Sounds like you're after http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808, or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49822 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32661

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Actually, I don’t remember; I think I learnt about its existence from an answer on this site, but cannot recall which one.