# Manipulating table and multicols

Tags: tables, multicol

I am trying to make a template for my master's homework. This master is organised by a university and a research center. So I thought of having on top of page(left and right) their logos. Bellow those logos I want to place their names.

I didn't have any trouble creating the logos. For their names I thought of using a table with left and right alignment so as to write their names, but despite the fact that I am teling it to place it `[H]` exactly here, it goes to the next page.

I also tried with `multicols` but I don't seem to be able to manipulate it either.

My code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[margin=2.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newtheorem{exe}{¢óêçóç}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.1\columnwidth]{ntua-logo}}\hfill
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.1\columnwidth]{demokritos-logo}}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lC{1cm}r}
National Technical University of Athens & ${}$ &National Research Center of Physical        Sciences\\
School of Applied Mathematics and Physical Sciences & ${}$ & Demokritos\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

%\begin{multicols}{2}
%National Technical University of Athens \columnbreak National Research Center of Physical        Sciences\\
%School of Applied Mathematics and Physical Sciences \columnbreak Demokritos
%\end{multicols}

\begin{center}\textbf{Master Title}\end{center}

\begin{exe}
$1+1=2$
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

Any ideas on that?

Comment: This is not a "figure" ie a labeled floating construct that you want to be positioned at a suitable page break. Just use \includegraphics without the figure environment, Perhaps best is to put it in a picture mode \put so you can position it exactly

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47497/implementing-line-based-corporate-design-in-latex/47514#47514

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you very much for your comment! You may be right that inserting logos as subfigures is a bit anorthodox so I tried `picture` and `put` and is working fine! Thank you for that! My problem is though, institute's names which I am trying to place just bellow logos. Any suggestion on that will be more than welcomed!

Comment: just  `\put{the name of the institute}` in the same picture environment at a coordinate that puts the text at the right place relative to the image

Comment: I think that your point was to use `put` and `picture` to add text at the exact position I want...I'll try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a `figure` ie a labeled floating construct that you want to be positioned at a suitable page break. Just use `\includegraphics` without the figure environment, Perhaps best is to put it in a picture mode `\put` so you can position it exactly, so:

```
\begin{picture}(0,30)
\put(0,0){\includegraphics{...}}
\put(30,-50){XXX University}
\end{picture}
```

See also [Implementing line-based corporate design in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47497/implementing-line-based-corporate-design-in-latex/47514#47514)