# Newcommand for fixed content not working

Tags: macros

I tried to generate a macro for fixed content, but it's not working and I was wondering why. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% this is working and puts A at the bottom of the page
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{%
\setlength\unitlength{1mm}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)%
\put(120,-250){\fbox{A}}%
\end{picture}\hfill}
\makeatother

% needed that page is not empty
test

% define a macro
\newcommand{\generateFixBox}{
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{%
\setlength\unitlength{1mm}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)%
\put(120,-250){\fbox{B}}%
\end{picture}\hfill}
 \makeatother
}

% apply macro, but not working?
\generateFixBox

\end{document}
```

The Latex error logs are confusing. I found the instructions for generating a fixed element [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47497/implementing-line-based-corporate-design-in-latex).

Comment: Your code is missing a closing bracket, at `\put(120,-250){\fbox{B}%`, so it should be `\put(120,-250){\fbox{B}}%`. Is that your desired output?

Comment: ah thanks for spotting that, but this is actually not what i meant. I fixed the bracket, but only "A" is printed but not "B". Do you know why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the catcode of `@`:

```
\newcommand{\generateFixBox}{
  \makeatletter
  \def\@oddhead{%
    \setlength\unitlength{1mm}%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \put(120,-250){\fbox{B}}%
    \end{picture}\hfill}
   \makeatother
}
```

At definition time, `\makeatletter` is *not* executed, but the definition text is already tokenized. Therefore the input text `\@oddhead` becomes `\@`, `o`, `d`, `d`, `h`, `e`, `a`, `d`.

`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should be moved outside the definition:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\generateFixBox}{%
  \def\@oddhead{...}%
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

there are several problems with your code.

first, you need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` at the outer level
so that the `@` is properly recognized in the command names.  and then,
these are not needed inside the definition of `\generateFixBox`.

second, in the definition of `\generateFixBox`, a closing brace is missing
to complete `{\fbox{B}`.

the result gives a replacement definition that is properly recognized.

in the following code, i've changed the vertical location of the `\fbox`
(it was disappearing off the bottom of the page, so i raised it a bit).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% this is working and puts A at the bottom of the page
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{%
\setlength\unitlength{1mm}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)%
%\put(120,-250){\fbox{A}}%
\put(120,-200){\fbox{A}}%
\end{picture}\hfill}
\makeatother

% needed that page is not empty
test

% define a macro
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\generateFixBox}{
%\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{%
\setlength\unitlength{1mm}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)%
%\put(120,-250){\fbox{B}%
\put(120,-200){\fbox{B}}%
\end{picture}\hfill}
% \makeatother
}
\makeatother

% apply macro, but not working?
\generateFixBox

\end{document}
```