# Creating a numbered-frames book template

Tags: tcolorbox, boxes, mdframed, framed, book-design

I want to create a template for a book document class (not beamer) where the entire book is written in numbered frames. Below is an example from Kleppner and Ramsey's *Quick Calculus* showing Frames 25 and 26:

[image]

The closest answer I have found is by [Yiannis Lazarides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/963/yiannis-lazarides) on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46593/234330. His full code is available on his [Github](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1971055) page.

But as a LaTeX newbie, I do not know of an elegant and efficient way to create this as a template for an entire book. Any suggestions on how I can proceed or where I can read more about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to build this `frames` with a `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{framecounter}
\setcounter{framecounter}{0}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=framecounter]{myframe}{%
    empty, breakable, title={\thetcbcounter\ }, 
    attach boxed title to top left, left=0pt, right=0pt,
    boxed title style={empty}, coltitle=black, 
    overlay ={\draw (title.east)--(title.center-|frame.east);},
    after upper = {\par\hfill Go to \the\numexpr\theframecounter+1\relax}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myframe}

\begin{myframe}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

[image]